# Webresource.axd and SciptResource.axd won't load on server

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, http-status-code-404, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I am just starting out with asp .net and I am a little bit lost trying to figure it all out and I was hoping someone here would be kind enough to help me.

Using VS12, I have selected a new ASP .Net Web forms application (with .net4 and c#). When I test it locally it is fine.

My problems start when I publish to my hosting provider (letshost.ie is the host /  harvestmile.com is the site url) as, while the page appears to load okay, on inspection I see errors stating that "GET" ScriptResouce.axd and WebResource.axd return a 404.

It also states that sys is not defined but i suspect that this is as a result of the earlier errors.

I feel like I am missing something extremely basic but I am totally lost in trying to figure out what that may be.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and hopefully I'll be able to return the favour over time as I learn more.

Thanks in advance! 
Ken

Answer (score 1):

Please enable the property "**EnableCdn**" for script manager to true.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that as soon as I get the chance and let you know(working through php/ajax right now so managed to sidestep the problem temporarily!).